# How to set up a home network

Tags: networking

I need help to list the devices and cables needed to establish a small network lan in my home.
I really don't know what kind of devices I need; is it router, switch,or access point.
I have 3 bedrooms in addition to 3 rooms as living , dining ,office room.

First : What kind of cables I need (cat5 or cat6 or else ) ?

Second: What are the devices needed and how to connect them?
If I want to connect all the network points in the rooms to a server (for eg : running windows 2003) in a way to provide each point with internet access + shared storage + gaming service.

I want to install 3 security cameras too is there a way to connect them to the server to record or I need a special device.

I do have an Internet connection 2mb Speed (ADSL) .

I need advices and opinions

Answer (score 3):

You can use CAT5e or CAT6, but just make sure you use plenum rated cable (this is for fire safety). You do not need a switch, just an all-in-one router/modem (which may even be wireless), which is sometimes provided by the internet service provider, and normally has 4 ports. I would just do wireless, it is easier. I hate running cables through walls. If something isn't wireless compatible, you can buy a wireless adapter pretty cheaply. Installation is pretty easy to as long as you get a decent brand. I have had very bad luck with IOGear.

If you needed more ports than provided by the modem/router, and didn't want to go wireless, you can get a small switch pretty cheap, in which you just connect that to the modem/router as if it were a computer (meaning in the same ports). It will pass through pretty easily.

Just set the file server up on the LAN. Connect everything to the router/modem and you will be fine. They will get private addresses via DHCP from the router/modem.

Gaming service is just through the internet.

The security camera just needs the camera hooked up to the server. If you run the cable through the walls that it fine. You might need to go get some RJ-45 wall mounts so it doesn't look crappy. To run the cables into the RJ-45 wall plates, you will need to strip the cable's coat, then strip the 8 pairs of cables down to copper and stick them in the back of the RJ45 wall mount plate with a screw driver or another tool that I can't think of the name of.

Found a picture of what it could look like! The router would be a router/modem. You need the modem to receive internet access. The router is for DHCP private addressing, so that multiple people can use the same internet connection. If you need to, put the other router between the modem/router and the computers, so that you can have extra ports.

[image]

If I missed anything, or was a little vague in any area, please comment...

Comment: Just one comment: "usually provided by the Internet service provider" is too broad a statement. It would depend on where you live, would vary from country to country, and personally, other than with a business account, I have never seen one give anything other than the modem, at least in my area.

Comment: O... Well here in America, AT&T gives you really nice ones, I just assumed that was the case in most places. AT&T seems like a pretty cheap place, and I assumed if they were doing it, other must do it too... Well at least it lets the person understand what they will need. :)

Comment: I have lived in America for 49 years (minus time serving in the military overseas), I can tell you that Comcast up here in the Northeast doesn't. My only point was that it can vary greatly from company to company, and by location since we have many people from all over the world here. I would have used the word "sometimes" to hedge my bet. Personally, I don't downvote (OK, I gave two early on, but I would prefer to just add a hopefully constructive comment), and not that I thought you would deserve one anyway, but some people might in a similar circumstance.

Comment: I will go ahead and change it, but it seems you are getting a little anal retentive about one word, which was a side-note. Sorry if you thought my last statement was mean at all, I was trying to agree with you. I even put a smiley face at the end so you know I was trying to be nice and supportive. I changed it to be nice because apparently you didn't like the one word. I assumed people would read the comments anyways. I do... They would then get the picture. You know what I mean?

Comment: no offense taken, and certainly none intended to be given. It is hard sometimes to imply tone when writing, but please don't think I was trying to get on you. And I did not mean that you had to change it. By the way, I just realized how much you added. +1. Again, no offense whatsoever. :)

Comment: OK, no problem. Thank you for the clarification. It is difficult to imply tone. Very much understood! Thank you VERY much for the +1.

Comment: I have FIOS and they too provide a nice router/wireless access point/switch.

Comment: Awesome @uSlackr! Great info! We could really use this information so that people know who to have be their ISP if they don;t have the coin to buy a wireless router/modem. Anyone else with another ISP, please provide the information! Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can do with a multi-purpose router...one that has Wireless and a switch combined. Then you can connect the router to the ADSL, and any computers, or other devices, can be connected physically to the switch, or wirelessly to the Wireless.

Cat5e or Cat6 cables will probably both do you fine for any wired connections, but if you are going to go through the trouble of putting them in the walls, use Cat6. You won't want to do it twice.

Comment: It is possible that you may not have enough ports on the all-in-one switch, and in that case, you would use a second switch connected to the first switch. If they are both gigabit speed, they will auto-negotiate, and you would just connect any port one one to any port on the other.